# How to replace or update "Style" attribute value by using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, attributes

I am feeding Data on website using VBA.
I am want to change/replace or update the value of "Style" attribute on that website.
HTML

```
<div class="timeline-row-item style="left: 556px;"></div>
```

I want to change the value from style="left: 556px;" to style="left: 300px;"

```
Sub test1()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.document.querySelectorAll("div[class*= timeline-row-iteml]").setAttribute ("style", left: 300px;")
```

How can i do this on Excel VBA.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns a collection. You cannot use setAttribute on that. You need an individual node

```
IE.document.querySelector("div[class*= timeline-row-iteml]").setAttribute("style", "left: 300px;")
```

Not sure if brackets are needed.

You can also use javascript

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('div[class*= timeline-row-iteml]').setAttribute('style', 'left: 300px;');"
```

If you want to do all matches then you will need to loop the returned nodeList

```
Dim elems As Object, i As Long
Set elems = IE.document.querySelectorAll("div[class*= timeline-row-iteml]")

For i = 0 To elems.Length -1
    elem.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'left: 300px;');"
Next
```

Comment: Thank You So Much for your Help..!! I did not need it for all matches but yet tried it, just to see how all matches will work. But "    elem.item(i).setAttribute('style', 'left: 300px;');"  " line was not accept by Excel VBA. But your javascript work really smooth. Thank You again Qharr